# ASP.Net Getting null value on submit in ActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created a controller and an edit page. The page should allow the user to update a subscription and save. Everything loads fine but when I submit the page the value is always null.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ReportSubscription reportSubscription)
{
    var rs = reportSubscription;
   
}
```

That and have a view that submits to it.

```
@model api.ReportSubscription

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Subscription";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Subscription" ))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-control" style="background-color:lightgray; width:500px">
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Description)
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" name="saveButton" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />        
   
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Loads fine but when I submit the value in the controller is always `null`.

Comment: I don't see any _input_ elements in your form. These are submitted to the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `@Html.HiddenFor()` to create a hidden field which will help the default model binder to working properly:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Subscription"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input type elements like (@html.editorfor) in cshtml file

Comment: This is only good - if you want to see the field - if not, use the other answer (`hiddenFor`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).